# AutoComplete functionality with Text Box by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jpa, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC (3.x) with JPA and JavaScript in our Web application.
    One question here regarding Auto complete functionality with Text box using javascript...

1 - In DAOImpl layer i have

```
public List<String> getProjectServiceList() 
   {
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("Select DISTINCT  
    req.projectServiceName from Request req where req.activeInd=1");
    List<String> projectServiceList = query.getResultList();
    return projectServiceList;

}
```

2 - and in RequestController.java i have set the model attribute projectServiceList

```
List<String> projectServiceList = getRequestService().getProjectServiceList();
    model.addAttribute("projectServiceList", projectServiceList);
```

3 - Now in JSP i have listed all the result in select box with foreach tag

```
<tr>
<td>Project/Service Name</td>
<td><select name="searchBean.projectServiceName" id="searchBean.projectServiceName" >
<option value="">All</option>
    <c:forEach items="${projectServiceList}" var="entry">
    <option value="${entry}" ${entry == baseBean.searchBean.projectServiceName  
? 'selected' : ''}>${entry}</option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

but my question is How to do same with auto complete text box,by using java script ( i 
    have model attribute 'projectServiceList' in jsb having all the list)

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

- Either you render your select html component with all of its options and find an autocomplete component that can transform that into an autocomplete field
- You render the autocomplete component and have an external request that will require your controller to send some data (xml/json) back.

Both solutions are covered by a couple of auto complete components that can do the trick.
The two that come to mind are:

- http://nicolasbize.github.com/magicsuggest/
- http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/